# Bash test condition result

Tags: bash

Having the code:

```
if [ 0 ]      
then
  echo "0 is true."
else          
  echo "0 is false."
fi
```

Why is the result `echo "0 is true.`??? Does it mean that bash evaluates `0` (zero digit) as `true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Does it mean that bash evaluates `0` (zero digit) as `true`?

Yes.

> `[ str ]` checks whether `str` is non-empty. It doesn't matter if `str` is `0`, it will still be evaluated for non-emptyness.

Source [[ 0 ] is true. Use 'false' instead](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2159)

> The `test` and `[` builtins evaluate conditional expressions using a set of rules based on the number of arguments.
>
> 0 arguments
>
> ```
>    The expression is false.
> ```
>
> 1 argument
>
> ```
>    The expression is true if and only if the argument is not null.
> ```

Source [test](http://ss64.com/bash/test.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Bash command line for Linux](http://ss64.com/bash/) -  An excellent reference for all things Bash command line related.
- [test](http://ss64.com/bash/test.html) - Evaluate a conditional expression expr.
- [How exactly does "/bin/[" work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336521/how-exactly-does-bin-work)

Comment: So everything inside`[]` is treated as string?

Comment: Effectively, yes. I will update the answer.

Comment: Thx for update. 2 questions more. 1.) What do You mean as `[` builtin? Do mean just single pair of double brackets`[]`? 2.) What is considered as a null argument? No argument (empty `[]`) == null argument or maybe sth. else/more?

Comment: 1/ `[` is a command built in to bash. See [What is the difference between a builtin command and one that is not?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/11454). 2/ Null is `[ ]` with nothing at all (ie 0 arguments)